# Property of being a transcendental number

Tags: terminology

Is there such a word as *transcendentality* to mean

> Proof of the transcendentality of the Euler number

?

Comment: IMO *transcendence* is better.

Comment: @YvesDaoust yes, also IMO. By the next search there will be a result. The down voter can... I just forgot what I wanted to say.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to know whether that expression is used, then the answer is yes. For instance, it was used in [this 1968 book](https://books.google.pt/books?id=3xQpXJ_hmBMC&pg=PA209&lpg=PA209&dq=transcendentality+number&source=bl&ots=Pl8kKzPpvy&sig=ACfU3U2p5C3vIQRwLRJJa0TGr88kwH_aWA&hl=pt-PT&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjIr5Lntc_iAhV7AGMBHfk5DcUQ6AEwDnoECAcQAQ#v=onepage&q=transcendentality%20number&f=false). Or in [these lectures on Analytic Number Theory](http://math.nsc.ru/~vdovin/lectures/numth_eng.pdf). But I suggest that you just say that $e$ is transcendental.

Comment: I like the notes you linked! In any case it seams that the word has some Russia connection (two books are not a great statistics, but, by the current times , a great argument)

Comment: @AaronLenz: derives from the latin *transcendere* ("to climb through").